# how do i check if an input is either a float or an integer?

Tags: python

```
print("hello")
mass_list=[]
volume_list=[]
x=0
while not x=="":
    x=input("Enter Mass: ")
    if x.isnumeric():
        m=float(x)
        mass_list.append(m)
while len(volume_list) < len(mass_list):
    x=input("Enter volume: ")
    if x.isnumeric():
        v=float(x)
        volume_list.append(v)
print(mass_list)
print(volume_list)
density=[]
for n in range (0,len(mass_list)):
    d=(mass_list[n])/(volume_list[n])
    density.append(d)
print(density)
avg_density=0
for n in density:
    avg_density = avg_density + n
avg_density=avg_density/len(density)
avg_density=format(avg_density,".2f")
print(avg_density)
```

this code take two lists from the user and i want for the program to accept floats

I want the user to input
10
15
20
""
1
1.5
2
and the output to be
10.00

Comment: You can't use `isnumeric()` for floats because the decimal point fails it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

In Python it's recommended to use the [EAFP principle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/5987) - don't try to verify the input, just use it and let it fail if it's wrong.  So instead of:

```
x=input("Enter Mass: ")
if x.isnumeric():
    m=float(x)
    mass_list.append(m)
```

Just do:

```
x=input("Enter Mass: ")
m=float(x)
mass_list.append(m)
```

If you need to detect an error, put the whole works in a `try`/`except` block.